# Strategy to patching code

Tags: version-control

We are following a standard pattern of promoting changes from trunk to branch to tag for a production release. When we need to patch a change in production, the changes are effected on the branch and a new tag is created from said branch. Currently, it is the author's responsibility to ensure that the change is also pulled to the trunk and tested. Unfortunately, in the heat of fixing the current production issue, testing and deployment, sometimes the author fails to pull the change to trunk and we realize this only in the next regression. One of my colleagues suggested that maybe we can change the policy to have all changes first tested on trunk and only changes from trunk can be promoted to the branch.

Pros:

- A policy solution to avoid missing out on pulling changes to trunk

Cons:

- When fixing a production issue, I want to test my immediate fix on the branch code that is going to move to production, rather than trunk which may have moved farther off. The time lost by making changes on a fast-forward copy and then retrofitting the patch for the branch code seems awkward. The counterpoint could be that there *may* not be that many scenarios where the trunk moves that differently from the branch (like a paradigm shift).

How are such things usually handled in open source projects? Also feel free to point out any other pros or mitigation of cons.